# Cat with wildcard

Tags: bash, shell, unix

The question is maybe trivial but I can't get it to work. I just want to merge 2 particular files present in multiple specific folders into a new single file again in each specific folder.

```
cat */folder_*/*/file.a */folder_*/*/file.b > */folder_*/*/file.c
```

but it does not work 'cause

```
-bash: */folder_*/*/file.c: No such file or directory
```

So I thought maybe for some reason `cat` can't create files (though it does), so I tried

```
touch */folder_*/*/file.c; cat */folder_*/*/file.a */folder_*/*/file.b > */folder_*/*/file.c
```

but again it does not work with `cat` or even `touch`.

Comment: I never used cat with such a thing. I suggest you to use find and then pipe with cat. Example : find -name 'file.a' | cat > blablabla

Comment: In case helps someone else, I got the same error _No such file or directory_ and my ‍♂️ was I was doing `cat "blah/*.json" > stuff.json` and  the glob started working when I did this without the quotes, `cat blah/*.json > stuff.json` 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for dir in */folder_*/*; do 
  [[ -d "$dir" ]] && ( cd "$dir" && cat file.a file.b > file.c )
done
```

I run the `cd && cat` in a subshell so you don't have to cd back to where you started.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use globbing for a destination file. You must fully specify the filename. It has nothing to do with `cat` specifically.

Comment: So the only alternative I can come up with is to loop through all the directories and subdirectories by `ls`, build up and save the entire path then execute the `cat` command for each file instance. Oh well... anyway thx.

Comment: @lorendarith: Don't loop with `ls` - use globbing `for f in *`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want something like this;

```
for a in  */folder_*/*/file.a; do
    # maybe continue if b missing
    cat "$a" "${a%.a}.b" >"${a%.a}.c"
done
```

Wildcards and redirections are processed by the shell; `cat` has no concept of wildcards, nor does it know where you are sending its output.

Comment: needed this for a rm command also, by putting `sudo rm $a` in the loop.

Comment: @blamb Don't forget the quotes; `sudo rm "$a"`! See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)